# Deploying Azure AD Apps, Azure functions with KeyVaults from Dev to QA to Prod

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, office365, azure-keyvault

I am developing an Azure function where I am using KeyVaults and Azure AD application to authenticate to Office 365. I am doing the development in my own tenant with my own Azure subscription, however I will need to move this to a QA environment which has its own instance of Azure AD and Office 365 subscription, then to the production environment which also has different Azure instance and Office 365.. How do we move the Azure AD App + Azure Function + KeyVault across multiple environments? Is the way to do it using ARM templates?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this case Brian? Did my propsal provide any vaule? If you could specify what kind of operations your function app need to have access to in offce 365 there might be possible to provide better answers..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you enable system assigned managed identity for your function apps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

Azure will create an identity for you, and this way you could dynamicaly assign roles and privileges in Azure AD for to these  identities through ARM-templates (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template).

You will be able to create infrastructure script independent of the environment. «Azure AD»-tenantid should be the only parameter you need to provide specifically per dev, QA etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll try it out and let you know.